# How to disable before time from current time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, timepicker

I want to set disable before time from current time in timepicker. I try under this code-

```
 $(function() {
    $(".callentry_time_formate").timepicker({
        dateFormat: '',
        showDate:false, 
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',            
    });

});
```

i used jquery-ui-timepicker but i am tired how can i solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use minDate and minTime,

```
 $(function() {
    $(".callentry_time_formate").timepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: '',
        showDate:false, 
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',            
    });

});
```